# Eclipse RCP Two IContentAssistProcessor not working properly

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

I am writing my own editor extending the general eclipse editor with two content assists.
The issue is when I overwrite `getCompletionProposalAutoActivationCharacters` in one of my content assist class, such as

```
   @Override
   public char[] getCompletionProposalAutoActivationCharacters() {
      String str = ".0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
      return str.toCharArray();
   }
```

for both content assist classes the `computeCompletionProposals(ITextViewer viewer, int offset)` are called when I enter any letter as described above in my editor, although the others returned `null`.

```
   @Override
   public char[] getCompletionProposalAutoActivationCharacters() {
      return null;
   }
```

I am desperate to find the issue.

Here is a snippet of my plugin.xml

```
     <extension
          point="org.eclipse.ui.editors">
       <editorContentTypeBinding
             contentTypeId="com.nwz.todo"
             editorId="org.eclipse.ui.genericeditor.GenericEditor">
       </editorContentTypeBinding>
     </extension>

       
<extension
       id="todo_general"
       name="General TODO"
       point="org.eclipse.ui.genericeditor.contentAssistProcessors">
   <contentAssistProcessor
      contentType="com.nwz.todo"
      class="com.nwz.todo.TodoCodeCompletionProposalComputer"
      categoryId="com.nzw.todo.codecompletion_general_category"
      activate="true">
   </contentAssistProcessor>
 </extension>

 
 <extension
       id="todo_additional"
       name="Additional TODO"
       point="org.eclipse.ui.genericeditor.contentAssistProcessors">
   <contentAssistProcessor
      contentType="com.nwz.todo"
      class="com.nwz.todo.TodoAdditonalCodeCompletionProposalComputer"
      categoryId="com.nzw.todo.codecompletion_additional_category"
      activate="true">
   </contentAssistProcessor>
 </extension>
```

Comment: Looking at `org.eclipse.ui.internal.genericeditor.CompositeContentAssistProcessor` that appears to be how it works if there are multiple content assist processors. An auto activation character from any processor will trigger calls to all compute methods.

Comment: How can I initialize it the Composite..Processor, but it will farther calls all compute methods.

Comment: Actually I can't see where CompositeContentAssistProcessor is used in the current release of Eclipse, it looks like the code in this area was rewritten recently. So if you aren't already using the current Eclipse 2021-09 try that.